# Stopped receiving e-mails from google groups

Tags: gmail, google, google-groups

I was receiving e-mails from a google group for the last 4-5 months.
But all of a sudden, I stopped receiving e-mails. I don't know the root cause of the problem. I didn't unsubscribe from the group, which I am certain of.

Any suggestions on how to start receiving e-mails once again?

Comment: Have you tried going into the group settings? Have you double checked that your subscription notifications haven't changed somehow?

Comment: how to check or change the group settings? How to check the subscription notification?

Comment: Instructions will take a lot of text, moving this to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try checking whether your subscription frequency has somehow changes, or your membership was altered in some way. To do this:

- Go here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!myforums
- Next to "Create Group," click on "Edit Memberships"

Make sure that the group you're looking for is in this list, otherwise you've been somehow removed :)

Next thing to check would be the email subscription frequency. You can find this in the dropdown in each group. Make sure it is set to "all email"

Comment: It worked good. Thank you. The drop down was set to 'No email' I changed it now. But I don't have any idea how it happened. Anyway restored to receiving emails.

Comment: If you ever had a out of office notification, Groups will see your account bouncing the messages and stop sending email notifications.